# Char validator will not only accept lower and upper case M/F

Tags: c++, validation, char

Hey im trying to validate a char to limit it to accpeting an m or f for male or female.  But it doesnt pass the while condition even when m or f is pressed and keeps looping the question.

Can anybody help me with this.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
char Validator :: getChar(string q)
{
    char input;
    do
    {
        cout << q.c_str() << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    while(!isalpha(input) && "M"||"F"||"m"||"f");
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"M"||"F"||"m"||"f"` part of your code doesn't do what you think it does. What it does is check the *ADDRESSES* of those string constants. Since they are all non-NULL, this expression simply returns true, so your condition, essentially becomes: `while(!isalpha(input) && true)` which is the same as `while(!isalpha(input))`.

Try this instead:

```
char Validator::getChar(const string &q)
{
    char input = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << q << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    while((input != 'M') && (input != 'F') && (input != 'm') && (input != 'f'));

    return input;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks very much.  And your right i thought that would have worked and i will know different from now on.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the `while` doesn't mean what you think it does. First, the `!` does not apply to the *entire* expression, and second, "equality" is not an *implicit* test. You need to write out everything you mean.

To test for equality, use the `==` or `!=` operators. You have to use the operators on *every* value you want to test; the operator doesn't "distribute" over a list of values like it would in ordinary English. Write your condition like this:

```
while (input != 'M' && input != 'F' && input != 'm' && input != 'f');
```

You can see that the `isalpha` call isn't necessary; if `input` isn't equal to any of the listed values, then it doesn't really matter whether it's an alphabetical character.

Another way to write it is this:

```
while (!(input == 'M' || input == 'F' || input == 'm' || input == 'f'));
```

Notice that I've another set of parentheses around the internal terms so that the `!` operator applies to the entire expression instead of just the first term.

Answer (score 1):

Just for an alternative approach to the terminating condition:

```
char Validator::getChar(const string &q)
{
    const std::set<char> valid_chars { 'M', 'm', 'F', 'f' };
    char input = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << q << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    while (!valid_chars.count(q));

    return input;
}
```